# Twillio Client To Client Call ios Never Recieve call method is didReceiveIncomingConnection

Tags: ios, twilio

I am working on iOS application where I am using Twilio SDK to manage client calling through device. To implement this i am using hello monkey demo application which i have successfully imported in Xcode.
After initial setup i am able to establish connection successfully but receiving delegate is no longer working. I have gone through complete twilio documentation but no success. Please suggest any alternative or solution ASAP. 
Here is my code of Hello Monkey sample project

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSLog(@"CLINT ID-----------------------     %@",name);

    //check out https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart to get a server up quickly
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://testdemo786.herokuapp.com/token?client=%@", name];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *token = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (token == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving token: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        _phone = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:token delegate:self];

    }
}

- (IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *to;
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"jenny"]) {
        to=@"client:tommy";
    }
    else
    {
        to=@"client:jenny";
    }


    to=@"4nmf5j";
    NSLog(@"TO---------------------%@",to);
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": to};

    _connection = [_phone connect:params delegate:nil];
}

- (IBAction)hangupButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [_connection disconnect];
}

- (void)device:(TCDevice *)device didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Incoming connection from: %@", [connection parameters][@"From"]);
    if (device.state == TCDeviceStateBusy) {
        [connection reject];
    } else {
        [connection accept];
        _connection = connection;
    }
}

-(void)connection:(TCConnection*)connection didFailWithError:  (NSError*)error{

    NSLog(@"Connection failed with error : %@", error);

}

-(void)connectionDidStartConnecting:(TCConnection*)connection{
    NSLog(@"connection started");
}

-(void)connectionDidDisconnect:(TCConnection*)connection{
    NSLog(@"connection disconnected");
}

-(void)connectionDidConnect:(TCConnection*)connection{
    NSLog(@"connected");
}

- (void)deviceDidStartListeningForIncomingConnections:  (TCDevice*)device
{
    NSLog(@"Device: %@ deviceDidStartListeningForIncomingConnections",   device);
}

- (void)device:(TCDevice *)device didStopListeningForIncomingConnections:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Device: %@ didStopListeningForIncomingConnections: %@", device, error);
}
```

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Want to post the code from your app?

Comment: hello please help me receiving delegate is never call for client to client call in iOS.

Comment: Happy to help you out, but its going to be a lot easier if you can show everyone your code so we can see if maybe you made an error. Can you post the code you are using in your application?

Comment: hello sir I have post my code. please check it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Its a bit hard to tell from the code you included, which does look correct to me.

Here are a couple of things to check:

1. Did you add the TCDeviceDelegate as a protocol on your interface:

   ```
   @interface FooViewController() <TCDeviceDelegate>
   ```
2. Are you sure you passing the correct client name to the connect method, and that the TwiML being returned from your TwiML Apps Voice Request URL is including that name properly?

   You could check this by looking at the [Twilio Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts) to see if Twilio logged any errors when retrieving or parsing your TwiML.  You can also check your Twilio [call logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls) to see what Twilio says the outcome of the inbound and outbound call legs were.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sir you are rightI have check my server url there is some mistake . I have fixed it Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

did you set the delegate to self? 
`_device = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:capabilityToken delegate:self];`